# Insert All into

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, sqlplus

Is there a difference between below with newline before select

```
INSERT ALL
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','STREAM',1,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','BNUMBER',2,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','Description',3,9,0)

SELECT * FROM dual;
```

and without new line before select

```
INSERT ALL
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','STREAM',1,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','BNUMBER',2,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','Description',3,9,0)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

I notice the first one doesn't insert anything in table and appears in log as

```
D
-
X
```

While second block without newline appears in log as 
**3 rows created.**

[image: Running by toad log given under script output vs running using sqlplus]

++LOGS

```
SQL> desc LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 LOOKUPTABLE_NAME                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)
 COLUMN_NAME                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)
 COLUMN_ORDER                              NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
 COLUMN_TYPE                               NOT NULL NUMBER(1)
 COLUMN_MODE                               NOT NULL NUMBER(1)

SQL> INSERT ALL
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','STREAM',1,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','BNUMBER',2,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','Description',3,9,0)

SELECT * FROM dual;  2    3    4    5  SQL> 

D
-
X

SQL> commit
  2  ;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE where LOOKUPTABLE_NAME='LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER';

no rows selected

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> INSERT ALL
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','STREAM',1,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','BNUMBER',2,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','Description',3,9,0)
SELECT * FROM dual;  2    3    4    5  

3 rows created.

SQL> select * from LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE where LOOKUPTABLE_NAME='LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER';

LOOKUPTABLE_NAME                 COLUMN_NAME                      COLUMN_ORDER
-------------------------------- -------------------------------- ------------
COLUMN_TYPE COLUMN_MODE
----------- -----------
LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER              BNUMBER                                     2
          0           1

LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER              Description                                 3
          9           0

LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER              STREAM                                      1
          0           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. You can add as much whitespace as you want (up to the maximum size for an SQL statement) without affecting the meaning of the query.

```sql
CREATE TABLE lookuptable_type (
  a VARCHAR2(50),
  b VARCHAR2(50),
  c INT,
  d INT,
  e INT
);
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT ALL
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','STREAM',1,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','BNUMBER',2,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','Description',3,9,0)

SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Will give:

> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

and:

```sql
INSERT ALL
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','STREAM',1,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','BNUMBER',2,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','Description',3,9,0)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

will also give:

> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=135aafefcfb893a59d8dc7c418088cf6)*

---

**Update**

> Why does SQL/Plus show this?
>
> ```
> D
> -
> X
> ```

SQL/Plus's default behaviour is to not accept blank lines in an SQL statement and assumes that this will terminate the statement ([SQL/Plus documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#sthref2874) and [relevant dba.stackechange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15820/execute-a-script-with-sqlplus-containing-blanks-semi-colons-and-forward-slashe)). To change this behaviour to allow blank lines you need to include the directive:

```
set sqlblanklines on
```

When SQL/Plus parses the statement with the blank line it will split it into two statements:

```sql
INSERT ALL
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','STREAM',1,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','BNUMBER',2,0,1)
INTO LOOKUPTABLE_TYPE VALUES ('LT_EMERGENCY_NUMBER','Description',3,9,0)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

The first is invalid syntax and the second is a valid statement and SQL/Plus will process it and display the output from the query.

If you enable blank lines then it will process the complete statement.

Comment: thanks a lot ,I'm using sqlplus to run this query ,so is it still no difference ,

Comment: @MustafaMahmod The user interface you are using *should* make no difference as it is not the UI that will parse the query but the SQL engine in the database on the server.

Comment: I expect the same ,but can you look again I added one snapshot for what's happening and I confirmed the same by select statement

So actually the empty line doesn't cause any issue using toad (I think it compile it as plsql) while using sqlplus not the same

Comment: I hope I'm not taking much of your time ,I updated some logs also 
It clearly show there's a difference

Comment: @MustafaMahmod As I said in the update `SET BLANKLINES ON`

Comment: Great thank you very much  ,can I make SET BLANKLINES ON always
I see in every session I have to type it again

Comment: [This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15820/execute-a-script-with-sqlplus-containing-blanks-semi-colons-and-forward-slashe) describes putting the directives in a `login.sql` script that will be run on login. You should be able to use that method.